# Finding longest zero sequence in a bit string

Tags: java, string, binary, time-complexity, logarithm

Given an bit string like "0001100001", I need to find the length of the longest zero sequence (4 in the example).

The algorithm should perform in O(log(b)) time, where b is the length of the string.

I have heard, that I have to shift the bits to the left somehow, to achieve the desired complexity, but I have no clue why...

I only know how to do it in linear time by iterating over the string.

How do I get logarithmic time?

Comment: Just reading the input will already take O(b) time.

Comment: @Henry: And what about, if we leave that out? Is there still a way to achieve log time? The hint from the assignment says that I need to shift the bits to the left: First one bit, then 2 bits, then 4 bits, 8 bits, 16 bits and so on... After each shift I need to use the AND function for the ones and that will give me the next sequence, which I shift... But I don't know how to use that

Comment: I can't proof it, but my gut feeling tells me there isn't.

Comment: How big is the input? Always 1 byte? Could use prebuilt lookup table ?

Comment: @Adam: The input size can vary, I think. And I have to do it by bit shifting because it's an assignment

Comment: I agree with @Henry. You need to examine every bit in someway, bit-shifting is an irrelevant implementation detail. I think whoever set this assignment either made typo in specifying O(log(b)) or doesn't understand big-O notation....?

Comment: If we don't assume that the whole string fits into one word, a shift operation will take O(b) time and also an AND operation will take O(b) time. On the other hand, if we assume the string fits into one word, i.e. its length is bounded, so is the runtime. This makes it an O(1) time.

Comment: probably this article could help https://www.quora.com/How-can-we-find-the-longest-continuous-subsequence-of-0s-in-binary-representation-of-an-integer-in-O-log-n-time-complexity

Comment: @Lashane: Thanks, that was a great article!

Answer (score 0):

```
private static int getLength(String input){
        int maxLength = 0;
        while (input.length() > 0) {
            int start = input.indexOf("10");
            int end = input.indexOf("01");

            if(end == 0){
                break;
            }
            String sub = input.substring(start, end);
            if(sub.length() > maxLength){
                maxLength = sub.length();
            }
            input = input.substring(end + 2);
        }
        return maxLength;

    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Since the number will be given as string, we can parse the number using

```
Integer.parseInt(String,Base)
```

If we are passing say 64 which is 1000000 in binary and the longest 0 length is 6, the while loop should run log2(64) which is 6, then this solution should be what you are looking for. Please check the solution below

```
public class CountZeroes {
private static long getZeroes(String s) {
    int x = Integer.parseInt(s,2);
    long count = 0, maxSoFar = 0;
    while (x > 0) {
        System.out.println("Running");
        if ((x & 1) == 1) {
            if (count > maxSoFar) {
                maxSoFar = count;
            }
            count = 0;
        } else {
            count += 1;
        }
        x = x >> 1;
    }
    return maxSoFar;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getZeroes("10000"));
    System.out.println(getZeroes("100000"));
    System.out.println(getZeroes("1000000"));
}
}
```

I have run this program for 16,32 and 64 and it works in log(n) time as there is no parsing character by character involved in this case and also used bitwise operator for the same. Please check once if this is ok.

Thanks

Comment: 1. `Integer.parseInt` parses string character by character 2. Right shift is equivalent to parsing character by character (it shifts only 1 bit), so you're efficiently doing it twice

Comment: I am right shifting an integer not a string which essentially divides the integer by 2 which should be the case for a log(n) time.

Comment: shifting divides integer by 2, but it DOES NOT decrease bit length by 2, try with number where all bits are 1 and calculate how many times shifting will be performed

Comment: Bit length can never be decreased, it can only be set to 1 or 0 as u are working with an integer which is 4 bytes, here the main essence is the loop should not run for x times if the number is x which is being taken care  of by the loop condition, that number should be greater than 0 and then division stops.

Comment: we're not working with 4 bytes integers, we're working with string which contains B bits, you've made some wrong assumptions and applied wrong understanding of big O notation

Comment: that is why the parseInt was used in the first place.

Comment: if your bit string length is <= 64 then you're working with fixed size input, which means O(1)